# Android version updation 5.0.2 to 6 and above

Tags: samsung, updates

I want install new version of Android in my Samsung galaxy core prime, but I can't because I am non-technical person. I don't know how I can do this. I found some tricks on search engine.but I am not professional person of mobile tech for for do this. I need complete guidance step by step. How I can do this without pc ?

[image]

Comment: Android is not a general purpose OS like Windows/Linux/MacOS. Every installation is specially "tailored" to the hardware. Therefore every device model need it's own special update. So it doesn't matter if you have a PC or not, if for your device is no update available then you can not install one => You have to buy a new phone.

Comment: I want how I can update through third-party app ?

Comment: @Epeople All you need to know is in the suggested duplicate above. In a nutshell, you can't.

Comment: Third-party apps can't update Android OS. You need a PC to flash [custom ROM](https://xdaforums.com/f/samsung-galaxy-core-prime-roms-kernels-recoverie.5490/) for your device. The usual step is to unlock the bootloader, flash a custom recovery, and then flash a custom ROM *specifically for your device model*. However, I'm not familiar with ROM flashing for Samsung devices specifically, so it could be wrong.

Comment: Note that custom ROMs are not provided by Samsung but are developed by end users. Often custom ROMs are experimental as not everything works.

Comment: It looks as if [5.0.2 is the final version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Core_Prime) for some models of this phone. Some can do 5.1.1.